# Is there a bug with the accessibility features of the lightning-datatable component

Tags: lightning-datatable

I'm facing an accessibility requirement to allow users to navigate from one clickable td content in a table to another using the tab key. This is the usual behaver when using tab with a table in HTML. However, when using Salesforce's data table LWC, using tab will either throw you out of the table if you are in navigation mode, or just move you one td to the right if you are in action mode.
According to Salesforce's documentation for the [lightning data table component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation), once you are in action mode, "You can navigate to each actionable element in the table using the Tab key". The problem is they do not specify what constitute "actionable element" anywhere on that page. It seems like all td elements are actionable. I would expect that only links, buttons and inputs, for example, will be regarded as actionable, and then navigating between them with the tab key will work.

Is that a bug? Or did Salesforce choose to drop the support for this basic behaver for their arrow based navigation instead?

Thank you all in advence,
Lior.